# Finding all permutations with condition

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I have a set $S = \{A,B,C,D,E\}$ with 4 slots.

The condition is the following: First and second slot must include a subset of $X=\{A, B, C\}$, while the third or fourth slot must have either $A$ or $B$ or $C$

Let me give you a few examples:

$A,B,C,D =$ O.K.
$B,C,D,E =$ NOT O.K.
$C,A,E,B =$ O.K.
$B,C,E,D =$ NOT O.K.

I have figured out there are 120 permutations altogether, but as I said, I am trying to find those which fit the condition. So I printed it out and count them. The final answer is 24.

But how to calculate that?

I have used following formula: $(3 P 2) · (1 C 1) · (2 C 1)$, but this returns 12. :(

$3 P 2$ as there are three letters that can / must be on the first two slots.

$1 C 1$ as there is one letter which can be on slot 3 or 4

$2 C 1$ as there are two letters which be on slot 3 or 4.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first two slots cannot contain $D$ or $E$, and the last two slots cannot be $\{D,E\}$, so a valid sequence contains at most one of $D$ and $E$. Because there four slots to fill, a valid sequence contains $A$, $B$ and $C$, and precisely one of $D$ and $E$. So we get every valid sequence by counting all permutations of $\{A,B,C,X\}$ with $X$ in the third or fourth place, and then substituting either $X=D$ or $X=E$. There are $2\times3\times2=12$ such permutations and hence $12\times2=24$ valid sequences.

Another way of counting is to first pick one of $A$, $B$ or $C$ for the first slot, and then another one for the second slot. This can be done in $3\times2=6$ ways. Then the last of $A$, $B$ or $C$ is either in the third or fourth slot, so this letter can be placed in $2$ ways. Then the last remaining slot is either $D$ or $E$, so it can be filled in $2$ ways. This gives a total of $6\times2\times2=24$ valid sequences.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are not allowed repeated letters, that the first two slots must be filled with two of A, B, C, and that the last two slots must contain the previously unused letter out of $\{A, B, C\}$.

As you correctly pointed out, there are six ways to fill the first two slots. These ways determine which letter out of $\{A, B, C\}$ must be used in the last two slots, namely the one not used in the first two slots. Call it $x$. It remains to choose in which slot $x$ used, and which of $D$ and $E$ is used in the remaining slot. Since there are two slots possible for $x$, and two choices of remaining letters, this gives $6\times 2\times 2=24$ total possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

Choose first two positions from $A, B, C$ and arrange them = ${3 \choose 2} \times 2!$ ways.

Now the remaining one of $A, B, C$ goes in either third position or fourth position.

If it is in $3rd$ position, $4th$ and $5th$ positions will be $D, E$ and they can be arranged in $2!$ ways.

If it is in $4th$ position, $3rd$ and $5th$ positions will be $D, E$ and they can again be arranged in $2!$ ways.

So total number of arrangements $= {3 \choose 2} \times 2! \times 2! \times 2! = 24$